# Python cross matching

Tags: python, python-2.7

After performing some algorithm(s), I end up with a list similar to the one below:

```
l = Set([(integer_4_digits, integer_n_digits], ..)
ex: l = Set([(1011, 123556), (1041, 424553), (1241, 464096), (1027, 589325), (1011, 432341), (1031, 423076)])
l = list(l) #all tuples must exist once. need to get items by index to match (perhaps?)
```

*Each tuple in this list has its first item a 4 digit integer (positive) and the second one, another positive integer.*

What I want is:

To create a new list (of lists or tuples) where all the possible combinations are grouped together (in a list or a tuple) with cross matching, including a fifth (or 3rd, if it's tuple+tuple+bool) element which is either `True` or `False` depending on whether or not if the first 4 digit integer of two newly matched-crossed tuples are the same or not (ex: `1011 == 1011` so Bool=`True`).

So after this process I want to get something like:

```
new_list = [(l[0], l[1], False), (l[0], l[2], False), (l[0], l[3], False), (l[0], l[4], True) ..
            (l[1], l[2], False), (l[1], l[3], False), (l[1], l[4], False), ..
            (l[2], l[3], False), (l[2], l[4], False), (l[2], l[5], False), ..]
```

As you can see, `new_list` does not contain duplicates matches. (`l[0]` is matched to `l[1]` only once, does not matter if the match tuple is a to be or b to a (`l[0],l[1],..`) or (`l[1],l[0],..`)

Now I can achieve this using nested `for e in l` loops and popping last `e` element and performing `e[0]` checks for bool and creating a new tuple (or list) and adding to the `new_list` list.

So how can I do this? How should I do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`itertools.combinations()`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations); it creates the combinations you are looking for. Together with a list comprehension, you should be set:

```
from itertools import combinations

[(i, j, i[0] == j[0]) for i, j in combinations(l, 2)]
```

Note that the `Set` type was made a built-in native type in python; just use `set` (lowercase) for the native version. We don't need to turn the set into a list for this to work; itertools doesn't care either way. You can even use the new `{elem, elem, elem}` set literal syntax.

This produces:

```
>>> from itertools import combinations
>>> l = {(1011, 123556), (1041, 424553), (1241, 464096), (1027, 589325), (1011, 432341), (1031, 423076)}
>>> [(i, j, i[0] == j[0]) for i, j in combinations(l, 2)]
[((1041, 424553), (1027, 589325), False), ((1041, 424553), (1011, 123556), False), ((1041, 424553), (1031, 423076), False), ((1041, 424553), (1241, 464096), False), ((1041, 424553), (1011, 432341), False), ((1027, 589325), (1011, 123556), False), ((1027, 589325), (1031, 423076), False), ((1027, 589325), (1241, 464096), False), ((1027, 589325), (1011, 432341), False), ((1011, 123556), (1031, 423076), False), ((1011, 123556), (1241, 464096), False), ((1011, 123556), (1011, 432341), True), ((1031, 423076), (1241, 464096), False), ((1031, 423076), (1011, 432341), False), ((1241, 464096), (1011, 432341), False)]
```

Comment: Hello Martijn, thank you very much! This is excellent and so elegant.  Wonderful solution. Cheers! BTW, if you've got a second, just out of curiosity I have a little Question. If you wanted this list to be 2x larger, with same elements in different positions (j, i, Bool), how would you go doubling it? Run the function twice on 2 variables and concat? Or any other elegant way for that as well?

Comment: @Phil: `result = result * 2` would double the list as well. Careful though; if your list contains mutable items (such as other lists, sets, dicts or custom class instances) you end up with doubled *references*, not values, inside that doubled list. For tuples and strings and integers, that's just fine.